# aws lambda funkction with 2 layers - serverless framework yaml file

Tags: aws-lambda, serverless-framework

I have in yaml file lambda function with two layers:

```
test1:
timeout: 120
memorySize: 650
events:
  - http:
      path: ....
      method: get
      async: true
      private: ....
handler: api/test/handler.handler
layers:
  - { Ref: XXXXXLambdaLayer }
  - { Ref: YYYYYLambdaLayer }      
package:
  include:
    - "./api/test/**"
  exclude:
    - "**"
```

is this correct way to use two or more layers in one function?

I am getting error:
Error: The CloudFormation template is invalid: Template format error: Unresolved resource dependencies [YYYYYLambdaLayer] in the Resources block of the template

Comment: What is the template look like for your layers? `Ref` is an internal macro function that is referring to the Logical Id of a resource - in your current code the logical id of that lambda is `test1` - so the Ref is looking for a layer named `YYYYYLambdaLayer` - what does YYYYYLambdaLayer in your template look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my serverless yml file look like this and working

```
service: app

provider:
    name: aws
    region: us-west-1
    layers:
        - {Ref: VendorLambdaLayer}
        - {Ref: AppLambdaLayer}

layers:
    vendor:
        path: ${file(vars.js):projectDir}vendor
    app:
        path: ${file(vars.js):projectDir}app
```

Please make sure you have defined YYYYLambdaLayer, it exists or we will share the relevant part of your yaml file.

Comment: First Letter of layer name must be capital case BAD: - {Ref: appLambdaLayer}; Good: - {Ref: AppLambdaLayer}   tnx a lot